# How to use Order in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a problem with the following CSS:

```
-ms-flex-order: -1;
-webkit-order: -1;
order: -1
```

We use this to put a generated Box before another one with different Content.
But this solution dosnt work in IE9 :(
I need a solution with pure CSS because we cannot change the Layout of the Generated Box.

Comment: You're still supporting IE9???

Comment: @JohnConde sadly 40 % of all Visitors of this Website uses this Browser :(

Comment: You could try to change it's position by using `float`. But with flexbox in IE9 i don't see anything beside a polyfill which could help you.

Comment: Interesting that you mention `order` doesn't work for you in IE9. And the rest of the flexbox layout does? You've probably got everything stacked in a column, so it appears flex is working, but it's just block layout.

Comment: Flex was never implemented in IE9. Support began in IE10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is not working in IE9. You need at least IE10. So no pure CSS solution for `order` property. You'll have to use polyfills or just apply all needed DOM manipulations via JavaScript.

Also you have an option to use `float`s and it might help in some cases.